# How does imputation work? I'm struggling to understand it

Tags: scikit-learn, data-imputation

I have a short question. I am implementing Scikit-Learn in Typescript and currently blocked at understanding & implementing imputer (mean and regression strategies).

Based on the example given on Scikit-Learn page, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>>> imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
>>> imp.fit([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3], [7, 6]])
Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)
>>> X = [[np.nan, 2], [6, np.nan], [7, 6]]
>>> print(imp.transform(X))                           
[[ 4.          2.        ]
 [ 6.          3.666...]
 [ 7.          6.        ]]
```

*How does imputation against `np.nan` in `[[np.nan, 2], [6, np.nan], [7, 6]]` work?*

- Could you please explain it to me how it works? I would appreciate any equations and background knowledge that I need to understand this.

Comment: If you are asking about Scikit then your question is off topic here.  If you  are asking something more general about imputation, then please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Is it fine to use Scikit Learn code as a reference?

Comment: -reference- -> example*

Comment: You can use code as a reference, but if you are trying to debug code, this is the wrong forum.

Comment: Question: Don't you think it still belongs to this place because it's not really asking about implementation detail but asking about how it works?

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to me to be about how Scikit works.  If that is incorrect, please modify that paragraph.

Comment: Ok, i've refactored the last paragraph as you suggested. I'm still using some code examples but I'm mainly asking for equation / theory behind the code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Imputer` is just calculating the mean for each column when `fit` is called. So column 1 has mean `(1+7)/2 = 4` and column 2 has mean `(2+3+6)/3 = 3.666...`.

The transform function just fills in the `NaN` fields with the column's mean value.

Comment: How about regression strategy? Could you explain that to me as well? Thanks in advance again

Comment: There is no regression strategy in sklearn, but you could do this yourself by training a model using the other columns as the dataset and the column to be imputed as the target, nearest neighbor is a simple and fast way to do this (use the value of your closest neighbor(s) for each missing field).